# Change TabNavigator tab after clicking StackNavigator's back button

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have an application that consists of 2 navigators: the `RootNavigator` is a `TabNavigator` with 5 tabs (A, B, C, D ,E), in which one of them (C) contains a `StackNavigator`.

**What I need to do is that whenever I get to the C tab and press the back button, I get navigated to the A tab.**

What I'm trying to do is: [1] create and bind a function on (C) screen that will be passed to their children screens and [2] call that function everytime the back button is pressed on the first child of (C).

```
const PointNavigator = StackNavigator(
{
  Camera: {
    screen: PointCamera
  },
  Code: {
    screen: PointCode,
  }
}, {
  headerMode: 'float',
    navigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#022436',
            shadowColor: '#000',
            shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
            shadowOpacity: 0.2,
            elevation: 4,
            position: 'relative',
        },
        headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerBackTitle: null
  }
});

class PointScreen extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.returnToHome = this.returnToHome.bind(this);
  }

  returnToHome() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
  }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <PointNavigator
          screenProps={ onBackPressed: this.returnToHome.bind(this) }
        />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default PointScreen;
```

The code above represents the (C) tab with its own `StackNavigator`. The code below is the `navigationOptions` of the first child screen of (C).

```
static navigationOptions = ({ screenProps }) => ({
    title: 'Pontuar',
    headerLeft: (
                  <HeaderBackButton
                    tintColor='white'
                    onPress={() => screenProps.onBackPressed()}
                  />
                )
});
```

The problem is that I can't manage to pass the function from the parent to the child navigator, always getting `undefined` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to include the Screen on the main StackNavigator and passed the function to navigate to it as props to inner Screens on the TabNavigator.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Can you try this?</s>

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'Pontuar',
    headerLeft: (
                  <HeaderBackButton
                    tintColor='white'
                    onPress={() => navigation.screenProps.onBackPressed()}
                  />
                )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check `this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');` in your PointScreen class is working?

And you don't bind again at `onBackPressed: this.returnToHome.bind(this)` since you bind it already in componentWillMount.